# How to make Struts 1.1 to work with Java 6?

Tags: struts, java-6

Currently i am working on a Struts 1.1 project which uses Java 1.4. 
I am going to migrate it to java 6. 
Will Struts 1.1 supports java 6? 
Is there any compatibility problems for struts 1.1 and java 6, if so what are they? 
Can you help me to get more visibility on this, like reference materials, suggestions, thoughts.

Thanks, 
Shunmuga

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered upgrading Struts as well? If you're not willing to migrate to Struts 2, you should at least update from 1.1 to 1.3.10.

Comment: Yes of course, i have to update the struts also. can you say me what are the files and jar files i have to add?

Comment: If it's not a large project, it's probably easier to remove Struts 1.1 completely and insert the newer version. Tracking down jars individually can be a pain, and having never upgraded from 1.1 myself, I don't know which ones you would need.

Comment: Is it okay if i add Struts 2 jar?

Comment: its a simple web application so we have planned to migrate to struts 1.3.10, hope it will accomplish my goal?